# Error while installing mysql on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I am getting error while installing MySQL

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
   mysql-server-5.7
   mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried various solutions one of them is

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After completely uninstalling mysql run the following command

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then reinstall mysql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But it did not worked.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

> The error message “Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)” indicates a problem with the package installer. This can happen in Ubuntu after a failed software installation, or if the installer becomes corrupted.

Method 1: Reconfigure dpkg Database
`sudo dpkg ––configure –a`

Method 2: Force-install the Software
If Method 1 did not work, you can attempt to fix the dependencies in the package installer.

`sudo apt-get install –f`

if non of theme worked try looking [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1)